# Using Amelia and decision trees

Tags: r, dataframe, decision-tree, imputation

I have a panel dataset (countries and years) with a lot of missing data so I've decided to use multiple imputation. The goal is to see the relationship between the proportion of women in management (managerial_value) and total fatal workplace injuries (total_fatal)

From what I've read online, Amelia is the best option for panel data so I used that like so:

```
amelia_data <- amelia(spdata, ts = "year", cs = "country", polytime = 1,
                                                   intercs = FALSE)
```

where spdata is my original dataset.

This imputation process worked, but I'm unsure of how to proceed with forming decision trees using the imputed data (an object of class 'amelia').

I originally tried creating a function (amelia2df) to turn each of the 5 imputed datasets into a data frame:

```
amelia2df <- function(amelia_data, which_imp = 1) {
  stopifnot(inherits(amelia_data, "amelia"), is.numeric(which_imp))
  imps <- amelia_data$imputations[[which_imp]]
  as.data.frame(imps)
}

one_amelia <- amelia2df(amelia_data, which_imp = 1)
two_amelia <- amelia2df(amelia_data, which_imp = 2)
three_amelia <- amelia2df(amelia_data, which_imp = 3)
four_amelia <- amelia2df(amelia_data, which_imp = 4)
five_amelia <- amelia2df(amelia_data, which_imp = 5)
```

where one_amelia is the data frame for the first imputed dataset, two_amelia is the second, and so on.

I then combined them using rbind():

```
total_amelia <- rbind(one_amelia, two_amelia, three_amelia, four_amelia, five_amelia)
```

And used the new combined dataset total_amelia to construct a decision tree:

```
set.seed(300)
tree_data <- total_amelia
I_index <- sample(1:nrow(tree_data), size = 0.75*nrow(tree_data), replace=FALSE)
I_train <- tree_data[I_index,]
I_test <- tree_data[-I_index,]

fatal_tree <- rpart(total_fatal ~ managerial_value, I_train)
rpart.plot(fatal_tree)
fatal_tree
```

This "works" as in it doesn't produce an error, but I'm not sure that it is appropriately using the imputed data.

I found a couple resources explaining how to apply least squares, logit, etc., but nothing about decision trees. I'm under the impression I'd need the 5 imputed datasets to be combined into one data frame, but I have not been able to find a way to do that.

I've also looked into Zelig and bind_rows but haven't found anything that returns one data frame that I can then use to form a decision tree.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know my post wasn't in the right format. I just edited it to include my code and what I've tried so far.

Comment: The usual procedure with multiple imputation is to perform a separate analysis in each imputed dataset. One should not attempt to combine imputed datasets and use the all in a single analysis.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated by @Noah, you would set up the multiple imputation workflow different than you currently do.

Multiple imputation is not really a tool to improve your results or to make them more correct.
It is a method to enable you to quantify the uncertainty caused by the missing data, that comes along with your analysis.

All the different datasets created by multiple imputation are plausible imputations, because of the uncertainty, you don't know, which one is correct.

You would therefore use multiple imputation the following way:

1. Create your m imputed datasets
2. Build your trees on each imputed dataset separately
3. Do you analysis on each tree separately
4. In your final paper, you can now state how much uncertainty is caused trough the missing values/imputation

This means you get e.g. 5 different analysis results for m = 5 imputed datasets. First this looks confusing, but this enables you to give bounds, between the correct result probably lies. Or if you get completely different results for each imputed dataset, you know, there is too much uncertainty caused by the missing values to give reliable results.